# GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server

Tags: java

I have got this error while running in server.
 ***GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Not running within active session)***. How to fix this?

Regards

Linda

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](http://www.rootninja.com/fix-gconf-exception-failed-to-contact-configuration-server-with-dbus-launch/) that explains some ways one might solve this problem.

If it's a permission problem on `~/.dbus` this should fix it:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.dbus
```